# Update column using duplicate value counter

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the duplicate value counter first, and then use it for another column to be updated.
How can I achieve that?

first, I have a table below:

| id | another_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 2 | null |
| ... | ... |
| N | null |

and then calculating duplicate value count for `id`:

| id | another_id | duplicate_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1 |
| 1 | null | 2 |
| 1 | null | 3 |
| 2 | null | 1 |
| 2 | null | 2 |
| 2 | null | 3 |
| 2 | null | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| N | null | X |

Finally, using all `duplicate_cnt` to UPDATE `another_id`:

| id | another_id | duplicate_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| N | X | X |

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: which myslq version are you using

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember what version I use, and can't access my environment during weekend... I think it's not latest but not so out-dated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend just reconstructing the table:

```
create table temp_t as
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
    from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t (id, another_id)
    select id, seqnum
    from temp_t;
```

Note:  Be very careful before using `truncate table`.  Check the results first!

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I took a note of your solution.
However, do you come up with any idea without reconstructing the table?
I'd love to learn UPDATE SQL if it's possible.

Comment: @mkzyk . . . If you had a primary key then that would be appropriate.  Without a primary key, I recommend simply reconstructing the table.

Comment: Actually I have also just auto increment id that is primary key.
so table is `no` (primary key), `id`, `another_id`.
is it appropriate for UPDATE SQL?

Comment: @mkzyk . . . You should ask another question.  This question has been answered.